# ActiveAdmin - how can I strip the filter / search terms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In ActiveAdmin, how can I strip the search term? (remove whitespace around " steve@example.com ")

I am trying to apply this to an email field.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  ...
  filter :email, # <- I want to strip! this search term
  filter :name
  filter :address_phone
  ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own ransacker in this simple case:

in the `User` ActiveRecord model:

```
ransacker :stripped_email, formatter: proc { |v| v.strip } do |parent|
  parent.table[:email]
end
```

in your User ActiveAdmin resource:

```
filter :stripped_email_cont
```

or `filter :stripped_email_eq`

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching#eq-equals

Answer (score 1):

With rails 5.2 and active_admin 2.2.0

File to `config/initializers/active_filter.rb`

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module ResourceController::DataAccess
    def apply_filtering(chain)
      filter_params = params[:q] || {}

      filter_params.each do |key, value|
        filter_params[key] = value.strip if value.class == String
      end

      @search = chain.ransack(filter_params || {})
      @search.result
    end
  end
end
```

Restart you server...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
  filter :email, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => proc { User.all.collect(&:email).map(&:strip) }
```

Comment: I have too many users to load up like that.  I just want to be able to paste email addresses into the search field and not worry about any surrounding whitespace that might come with the copy/paste. Valid emails aren't allowed to have surrounding whitespace, so stripping the search address will never hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Monkey patch will do it: something like this will work for "cont" queries

```
  module ActiveAdmin
    module ResourceController::DataAccess
      def apply_filtering(chain)
        filter_params = params[:q] || {}
        filter_params.update(filter_params) do |key, value|
          key.include?("cont") ? value.strip : value
        end

        @search = chain.ransack(filter_params || {})
        @search.result
      end
    end
  end
```